# Unable to create WordPress wp-config.php file on ECS

Tags: wordpress, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I tried running a WordPress container on ECS (Launch Type: EC2) and mounted an EFS Access Point (/var/www/html) as my volume. In my Task Definition, I gave all my environment variables but I keep getting this error in my logs:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 87: wp-config.php: Permission denied
```

I tried to install Wordpress manually but I got a **Unable to write to wp-config.php file message**.

My EFS Access Point uses 33 as its owner UID and GID with 777 permissions but I still get this error. It has the elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess policy.

Any advice?